# return first record after sum of specific value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table where I want to get the first record after a certain value is reached with sum. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

So - for the following table, summing the amount column for a specific user (eg user 1) I want the record where the amount gets to zero or below, in this case record with deposit_id 8.

```
deposit_id |   user_id            |   amount
-----------------------------------------------------------
1          |   1                  |   +10
2          |   1                  |   +5
3          |   2                  |   +10
4          |   1                  |   +5
5          |   2                  |   +5
6          |   1                  |   -15
7          |   1                  |   -3
8          |   1                  |   -3
9          |   1                  |   -5
```

What would the best way to structure a query for a specific user to sum the values and stop when the value has reached 0 or below and return the record which pushed it over the edge (the first record where total sum of amounts <= 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cumulative sum can be reached with a Window function and a CTE, the difficult part is to stop it.

```
sum(amount) over (partition by user_id order by deposit_id)
```

> ```
> create table foo(deposit_id int,user_id int,amount int);
> insert into foo values
> (1,1,10),
> (2,1,5),
> (3,1,5),
> (4,1,-15),
> (5,1,-3),
> (6,1,-3),
> (7,1,-5);
> ```

> ```
> with CumSum as
> (
>     select deposit_id, user_id, amount,
>            sum(amount) over (partition by user_id order by deposit_id) as total
>     from foo
> )
> select deposit_id, user_id, amount, total
> from   CumSum
> order by user_id, total desc;
> ```
>
> ```
> deposit_id | user_id | amount | total
> ---------: | ------: | -----: | ----:
>          3 |       1 |      5 |    20
>          2 |       1 |      5 |    15
>          1 |       1 |     10 |    10
>          4 |       1 |    -15 |     5
>          5 |       1 |     -3 |     2
>          6 |       1 |     -3 |    -1
>          7 |       1 |     -5 |    -6
> ```

To get the first element where total <= 0

> ```
> with CumSum as
> (
>     select deposit_id, user_id, amount,
>            sum(amount) over (partition by user_id order by deposit_id) as total
>     from foo
> )
> select   deposit_id, user_id, amount, total
> from     CumSum
> where    total <= 0
> order by user_id, total desc
> limit 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> deposit_id | user_id | amount | total
> ---------: | ------: | -----: | ----:
>          6 |       1 |     -3 |    -1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e613ffd3fbaa7881bfa83fd07dd0b353)*